# How to apply the drm function to subsets of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, loops, split, lapply, drc

I want to do dose-response modelling with a large dataset. Is there an option to use e.g. the lapply or map function to apply the drm function to the individual subsets of the data? Or has this problem possibly to be solved by a loop?

I successfully structured my data by the split function and got a list of 73 dataframes. In the next step I want to do the dose-response modelling individually for all subsets but without naming every subset individually. The lapply function returns the error that the object 'response' could not be found.
Any ideas how I can solve my problem without an endless code? I am an absolut beginner in R and apologize if this is a stupid question. Thanks in advance for every comment!

`data_split <- split(data, f = list(data$sample, data$date), drop = TRUE) lapply(data_split, drm(data=data_split, response ~ dose,fct=LL.5())`

Comment: check ```names(data_split1)```(note: I added the 1 to denote subset one, but use whatever you named your subset as). This will let you know if your column `response`is even there.  Note: The response variable needs to be % mortality.  If you `response`variable is not expressed as such, I do not believe your code will work (at least not in my experience using the ```drm()```function.

Before running ```lapply()```can you run the ```drm()```on one of your subets, or do you still get an error?

Comment: Use the `curveid=` argument of `drc`.  Also please read the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular questions should be reproducible so any one else can run them.